# Using `event_generate` when tkinter runs in a new thread

Tags: events, tkinter

I need to generate virtual events for a tkinter window running in a separate thread. Calling `event_generate` from non-gui thread is supposed to be safe and it works well, when tkinter runs in the main thread and events are generated in another thread.

For a certain reason I need that the statements generating the events run in main thread (more specifically, I want those statements to be in the toplevel of the module).

But, when I do `root = Tk(); root.mainloop()` in a new thread and `root.event_generate("<<my-event>>")` in the main thread, I get stack overflow. When I swap the threads (`root = Tk(); root.mainloop()` in the main thread and `root.event_generate("<<my-event>>")` in a new thread) then everything works again.

I have taken care that root is fully construted (and also idle), before I try generating the event.

Any ideas how to get this setup working?

(I'm using Python 3.2.3)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself: put only `root.mainloop()` in secondary thread, keep `root = Tk()` in main thread.

Comment: Damn it, Linux and OS X require tkinter to be run in main thread only: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1835036/261181